# Back button title missing with long screen title in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am seeing that "Back" button title is missing when my screen title is big. I needed to show the entire title. Is there any workaround to this?

Please see attached the screenshot of navigation bar I see with long title.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your screen title smaller. You can take control of it by using a `titleView` that's a UILabel. The advantage is that you can set its size, and that it can truncate its text and/or make the text occupy two lines if the text is too big (rather than just growing, as the `title` does).

Comment: agreed. shorten the title or use an image. truncating is an option, but should be your last resort.

Comment: you could also change appearance of your Cancel button to something like an X. that brings up a question: is the behavior of Cancel button different than Back button? if not, then you may want to consider dropping one to reduce UI redundancy and give you some more pixels to play with.

Comment: Another possibility: put the title info (here, "MacBook Pro 15-inch Retina") into the main interface, not in the `navigationItem`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *iv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,170,35)];
[iv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

_titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 35)];
_titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[_titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
[_titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[_titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[_titleLabel setText:@""];
_titleLabel.clipsToBounds = false;
iv.clipsToBounds = false;
[iv addSubview:_titleLabel];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:iv];
```

also you need
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel* titleLabel;