# How to prevent UINavigationBar items hiding if title is long in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar

I have a problem with UINavigationBar in iOS 6: if navigation bar has too long title, then second (there are two button items) of right bar button items becomes hidden. iOS 7 is okay (must be fixed)

How to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can customize the title label of UINavigationBar. You can set its minimumFontSize property so make the text adjustable.

OR

For iOS 6 you can use below code, so that you can provide a custom label:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30)];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setText:text];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:label];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `titleView` with an embedded `UILabel` inside to have full control of how the title is displayed and how much it can "grow".

Answer (score 0):

This question is the same as [Back button title missing with long screen title in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029173/back-button-title-missing-with-long-screen-title-in-ios-7)

And the answer is the same answer I gave there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22029442/341994

I quote that answer:

> Make your screen title smaller. You can take control of it by using a `titleView` that's a UILabel. The advantage is that you can set its size, and that it can truncate its text and/or make the text occupy two lines if the text is too big (rather than just growing, as the `title` does).

Comment: There is iOS7, I have iOS6 issue

Comment: @RomanTruba A UILabel `titleView` will work for all iOS systems.